# R - How to add columns to a dataset incrementally using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, naivebayes

I'm trying to get the error rates for a Naive Bayes classifier, by adding in each variable incrementally. For example I have 25 variables in my dataset. I want to get the error rates of the model as I add in one variable at a time. So you know it would output the error rate of the model with the first 2 columns, the error rate with the first 3 columns, then with the first 4 columns, and so on up to the last column.

Here is the pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve

```
START
IMPORT DATASET WITH ALL VARIABLES

num_variables = num_dataset_cols
i= 1

WHILE (i <= num_variables)
{
   CREATE NEW DATASET WITH x COLUMNs

   BUILD THE MODEL 
   GET THE ERROR RATE

   ADD IN NEXT COLUMN

   i = i + 1
}
```

Here is a reproducible question. Obviously you can't build a NB classifier with this data, but that's not my problem. My problem is adding in the columns one by one. So far, the only way I can do it is by overwriting each column. For a NB classifier, the first column is the class node, so there must be at least 2 columns starting off in order for it to run.

```
#REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
col1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
col2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
col3 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
col4 <- c("n","y","y","n","y")
col5 <- c("10", "15", "50", "100", "20")

dataset <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4,col5)

num_variables <- ncol(dataset)

i <- 1

while i <= num_variables 
{
data <- dataset[c(1, i+1)]
str(data)

#BUILD MODEL AND GET VALIDATION ERROR

#INCREMENT i TO GET NEXT COLUMN
i <- i + 1

}
```

You should be able to see from the `str(data)` that each time the column is overwritten. Does anyone know how I could go about adding each column without overwriting the previous one? Someone suggested an array to me, but I'm not too familiar with arrays in R. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
col1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
col2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
col3 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
col4 <- c("n","y","y","n","y")
col5 <- c("10", "15", "50", "100", "20")

dataset <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4,col5)
dataset

num_variables <- ncol(dataset)
num_variables
i <- 1

while (i <= num_variables) {

data <- dataset[, 1:i]

print(str(data))

#BUILD MODEL AND GET VALIDATION ERROR

#INCREMENT i TO GET NEXT COLUMN
i <- i + 1

}

Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
NULL
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: num  1 2 3 4 5
NULL
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ col3: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
NULL
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ col3: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
 $ col4: Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 1 2 2 1 2
NULL
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ col1: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ col2: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ col3: logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
 $ col4: Factor w/ 2 levels "n","y": 1 2 2 1 2
 $ col5: Factor w/ 5 levels "10","100","15",..: 1 3 5 2 4
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great! It seems like the only significant change you made was adding in : to the line `data <- dataset[, 1:i]`. Does that increment each row one by one?

Comment: You are welcome. yes, that''s the main change. Also don't forget the brackets () in the while statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append` function after defining `output` variable

```
data <- dataset[c(1, i+1)]
append(output, data)
str(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the "assign" function within a while loop can be helpful for issues like this. You don't show the model syntax, but something like this should work:

```
dataset$errorrate <- [whatever makes this calculation, assuming it is vectorized]
name <- paste0(errorrate, i)
assign(name, dataset$errorrate)
```

...

This should leave you with i variables containing error estimate for each model run. If you are looking for one parameter estimate per model you can assign the single estimate a unique name within the global environment using the process above and then rbind them together after the loop has finished

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't think this will work for me, because the package I'm using to get the cv error rate doesn't give me a single value I can assign to a vector. However it should work great for my logistic regression model!